# How to do an exact type checking without having runtime side effects in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript. See the simple example:

```js
// My bird collection
interface Birds {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

db.find({colour: "black"}).limit(1)
// here, the statement is using "colour" instead of "color".
// I want to prevent these scenarios. So, I tried

db.find({["colour" as keyof Birds]: "black"}) // I thought this would produce error. But this will not.

// What I'm doing:
const colorKey: keyof Birds = "color"; // using "colour" gives error here, as expected.
db.find({[colorKey]: "black"})

// but this is producing a lot of variables and runtime code. Is there any cleaner workaround?
```

The same can be applied to other cases when working with multiple teams and projects

```js
// types published by Team A/Project A.
type Collections = "Birds"|"Cats";

// these types consumed by Team B/Project B like:
db.collection("cats" as Collections) // no errors. But I'm using "cats" instead of "Cats"

const catCollectionKey: Collections = "Cats";
db.collection(catCollectionKey) // OK
```

Question: How to do an exact type checking without having runtime side effects in typescript?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgIwFwEMwE8YF4YG8C+A3DAPQkwBmIATjAKYAeKAtgA4A2dMrArtayAh0IAOhgAhHrCgALAJZgA1jFlyIMFOpQxqdFO3gooKBJq4LoaYHREBYAFAOyMALKYEc6nBih2nYFBy4A4KUHTUFCjWEp5w6rgOMDBgLHRIMNDUCgDmhIk+IOw06Zk5efb4Dg6IIhQKcAAUuL4gfOkARAjsUYrt+ACUIuxyzHJQDQCM-U7kMuF0ADQqcxnGYcx0YLBqMDwQOTDtLXztMBZhKN4gFIct1O129s4AkjAA7mjSINy6AG6b0jmQgy1hSWUEYgAyiAlq8oFk6HAqvYanUwI1cABtI6FVr3DTqRR0dDXGJeCAAXQ6XR6fX6pHIcJkrWyMkBOzerXY3lY1BAcB40XCfOoYkk7PUbzkfmSICgjxmMAA6jIjDBngByZjwEA5JAOUCQWB3ADSxPSRJJN3EsXUOBxRXuxGcewODrxp2ycn+6mFNBgc10S009AYrDoAURj1R9SamNNxKphxpwF6A2RzgAtNmc7m8-mC4Xs4qAIJgOWBnxmZGIfIiXSgLwNDWsFDUPlQTMAdgAHF2AKwQDXTexJEQ8VhwIx0Jr5JJ3DrZXSbdoLOeUEAgalt1frlIbdIagAKbY7Gvy+AJZLi9Oc5fo7f9UtkG63nR3ireqtgr1V-xU3xwFuBrgNAuyTtOAAiRgoOkNrktgeD5PuaQwMep40Bqa6jgUjqHkudCbOeFTVAg9YRjQjQthhna9gOQ6DBOU5hA0TFQTB-RAA)

*I understand why `as` is not producing any errors.* But is there a cleaner workaround/syntax/operators for this? like

```js
db.collection(<Exactly<Collections>>"cat") // ts-error. "cat" is not assignable to "Cats"|"Birds"
// or
db.collection("cat" strictlyAs Collection) // ts-error. "cat" is not assignable to "Cats"|"Birds"
```

Comment: `db.find({color: "black"} as Birds).limit(1)` you need to tell ts compiler your object is `Birds` by type assertion

Comment: You are not creating a lot of variables, those are type definitions. Typescript use them to understand yow code, once the code compiles all them types and stuff disappears. So don’t worry. Unfortunately that is one of the downsides that come with typescript. I recommend you to first learn what are the different types, interfaces, modules, namespaces. Learn what they are and how they are used, before writing actual code

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi This was my problem: In `{color: "black"} as Birds`, `{color: "black"}` does not properly represent the `Bird`, you need `name` as well. But still you are able to use it without errors. I was looking for an operator/way similar to the `as` but a more stricter one. So that when I use `{color: "black"} as Birds` I might get an error like `{color: "black"} is not assignable to Birds, property "name" is missing`

Comment: I found the solution use `satisfies` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312320/3370568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Typescript 4.9 (Nov 2022), we now have a [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-rc/#satisfies) that does exactly this. You may want to replace the `as` in your question with `satisfies` operator.

```
db.find({colour: "black"} as Partial<Bird>).limit(1)

// to

db.find({colour: "black"} satisfies Partial<Bird>).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline type checking:

```
db.find({colour: "black"} as Partial<Bird>).limit(1)
```

In your `"cats" as Collection` example you are tellings typescript that "cats" is a Collection while it actually isn't. This prevents type warning from being thrown instead.

This can be solved with a type-checking function as suggested [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) but it has a runtime side effect:

```
function asType<T>(value: T) {
  return value;
};
```

Then use like this:

```
db.collection(asType<Collection>("cats"))
```

However doing it like this means everyone needs to type assert their input every time they use the `find()` or `collection()` functions which can be forgotten or asserted with the wrong type.

Consider making the parameters of the functions typed instead.

Comment: Please note this is not the answer I'm looking for. I used `db:any` as an example purpose (for not getting "var db not defined" error). I've updated the comments on the playground. My question was is there any easy way to enforce type checking in-line. Like the purpose of `as` in `birdVar as Bird` - but stricter. So please delete this answer as it is misleading.

Comment: You can get the same behaviour in-line. but if you tell the `find()` function what type to expect you don't have to do this every time you use it. I'll change my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: This solution works. But this has runtime side effects. For just to achieve type checking we are adding a function to the runtime code.

Comment: True, the link before the example is from the TypeScript issue tracker on GitHub. you can subscribe there to be notified when this feature is added to the language. the issue was created in 5 years ago so don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Fast-forward to Nov 2022, we now have the `satisfies` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312320/3370568